# eclipse debugger - stepping over only one method within another

Tags: eclipse, debugging

how come that when the debugger pointer is on this line " object1.method1(object2.method2()); "  stepping over skips both of the methods, instead of just the method2 ?
I always have to step into the method2 if I want then to step into method1. Usually method2 is some kind of low level stuff I'm not interested in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Point the cursor on "method1" and hit Ctrl-F5 (step into selection), or use Run / Step Into Selection menu, or Ctrl+Alt-Click on "method1".

Comment: Eugene I'm not sure we are using the same debugger, maybe you have it set up somehow, but ctrl-click on method one is just stepping into that method within editor, as it would be without debugging and pointing cursor on the method1 and hitting ctrl-f5 steps into the method2

Comment: I am sorry, it is Ctrl+Alt-click, but it can be configured in Window / Preferences / General / Editors / Text Editors / Hyperlinking